# how to print a javascript object's elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

i am new to javascript and i currently have an `object` printed to console when i use the following code:

```
clickEvents: {
    click:function(target) {
        console.log(target);
    }
}
```

when i view console i can see the following object:
[image]

i am banging my head against a wall to write code that takes the object and prints it to a div using the `.append()` method. i am extermely new to working with javascript objects, and would appreciate any help trying to tease out an object and/or print the object data.

is `events` the object name? would i tease out the eventDate using something like `events->eventDate`?

Comment: Would would do something like console.log(target.events[0].eventDate)

Comment: You want to print the entire object? Objects are made up of properties that include other objects, arrays, strings, and numbers.

Comment: i am extremely new to javascript. i need to learn how to tease out the main data elements of the object inside html

Comment: i can use `.append(target.events[0].eventDate)` and show that data - but is that the preferred method?

Comment: @HollerTrain Unless you can make your object simpler. If you need more than 1 event in your `target` object, then yes, this would be the preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have a div that you want to append to already, but you would do something like this ->

`document.getElementById("toBeAppendedTo").innerHTML = target.events[0].eventDate;` where `toBeAppendedTo` is the id of the div you're trying to add this text to.

`append()` is a jquery function, not a javascript function.

That won't have any formatting and will just be the string value `07-28-2017` in a div.

Comment: Just curious - you've never been on SO before and you're a developer? Did you mostly just read questions without making an account?

Comment: Ya. I've used the site quite a bit but haven't contributed to it (or signed up) until now. Maybe I was worried I'd make a fool of myself with a wrong answer? I dunno what it was.

Comment: Actually impressive, idk if I'd be able to learn without asking anything on SO. Hats off to you.

Answer (score 0):

I've made this over ~15 minutes so it's imperfect; there are types and edge cases surely unaccounted for and the design of the function could be better - not to mention that performing all of this as a giant string and then setting that as HTML is likely bad practice (I'm used to React now, ha!). Regardless, this will iterate over any array or object you pass to it and print it all in a big `<ul>` recursively.

```
const targetEl = document.querySelector('.js-target')

if (!targetEl) return

// Small helper functions
const isObj = data => typeof data === 'object' && !Array.isArray(data) && data !== null
const isArr = data => Array.isArray(data)

const dataToHTML = (data, noNode = false) => {
  if (isObj(data)) {
    const accumulator = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, set) => acc + `<li><strong>${set[0]}</strong>: ${dataToHTML(set[1], true)}</li>`, '')

    return `<ul>${accumulator}</ul>`
  }

  else if (isArr(data)) {
    const accumulator = data.reduce((acc, item) => acc + dataToHTML(item), '')

    return `<ul>${accumulator}</ul>`
  }

  else return noNode ? data : `<li>${data}</li>`
}

const logHTML = dataToHTML(exampleData)

targetEl.innerHTML = logHTML
```

Assuming that your data/variable is named `exampleData`.

Any questions pop them in the comments :-)